# How to transform PageRequest object to query string?

Tags: rest, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm writing an *RESTful API* which consumes another *RESTful Data API*, and I'm using Spring Data.

The client side send the page request using query params like:
http://api.mysite.com/products?page=1&size=20&sort=id,asc&sort=name,desc

And I transform the *params* to *PageRequest* object and transfer it to the Service Layer.

In the service, I would like to use TestTemplate to interact with the Data API which use a URL, and **How can I transform the PageRequest object to a query string** like

> page=1&size=20&sort=id,asc&sort=name,desc

then I can request data like:

```
restTemplate.getForEntity("http://data.mysite.com/products?page=1&size=20&sort=id,asc&sort=name,desc",String.class)
```

Answer (score 3):

I know I am a bit late on this answer, but I too was not able to found an already implemented way to do this. I ended up developing my own routine for doing this:

```
public static String encodeURLComponent(String component){
    try {
        return URLEncoder.encode(component, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("You are dumm enough that you cannot spell UTF-8, are you?");
    }
}

public static String queryStringFromPageable(Pageable p){
    StringBuilder ans = new StringBuilder();
    ans.append("page=");
    ans.append(encodeURLComponent(p.getPageNumber() + ""));

    // No sorting
    if (p.getSort() == null)
        return ans.toString();

    // Sorting is specified
    for(Sort.Order o : p.getSort()){
        ans.append("&sort=");
        ans.append(encodeURLComponent(o.getProperty()));
        ans.append(",");
        ans.append(encodeURLComponent(o.getDirection().name()));
    }

    return ans.toString();
}
```

It is not complete, there probably are a couple of details that I am missing, but for my user case (and I think for most of them) this works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to iterate through the request parameters from your other API request, and then pass all the parameters values into the new Url for a new API request.

sudo code could be:

```
//all query params can be found in Request.QueryString
var queryParams = Request.QueryString; 

private string ParseIntoQuery(NameValueCollection values)
{
   //parse the identified parameters into a query string format 
   // (i.e. return "?paramName=paramValue&paramName2=paramValue2" etc.)
}
```

in your code, you will then do this:

```
restTemplate.getForEntity(urlAuthority + ParseIntoQuery(Request.QueryString));
```

simple as that.  Hope that answers?

Answer (score 0):

```
UriComponentsBuilder uriComponentsBuilder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl("http://data.mysite.com/products");

    addRequestParam(uriComponentsBuilder, "page", pageable.getPageNumber());
    addRequestParam(uriComponentsBuilder, "size", pageable.getPageSize());

    String uri = uriComponentsBuilder.toUriString() + sortToString(pageable.getSort());
```

addRequestParam method:

```
private static void addRequestParam(UriComponentsBuilder uriBuilder, String parameterName, Object parameter) {
    if (parameter != null) {
        uriBuilder.queryParam(parameterName, parameter);
    }
}
```

implement sortToString(Sort sort) method as @Shalen. You have to obtain something like this: &sort=name,asc&sort=name2,desc. Return "" if Sort is null;

Answer (score -1):

***you can pass as new :***

new  PageRequest(int page,int size)

***And in repository layer you can write as:***

```
Page<User> findByName(String name,Pageable page)
```

in place of  **Pageable page** you have to pass **new PageRequest(int page,int size)**

***For ascending order you can refer this:***

```
List<Todo> findByTitleOrderByTitleAsc(String title);
```

Comment: I don't think you got my question, my api need to transfer the request parameters to another restful api.